# How to fix problem with ListView on django 2.2

Tags: django

I have a problem with ListView and can't get queryset from the genre movies. If I go to categories I can see the movie category, but if I want to see movies by genre I see an empty list.

```py
views.py

class MovieListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'movies'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.kwargs.get('category') is not None:
            movie_list = Movie.objects.filter(
                category__slug=self.kwargs.get('category'),
                published=True,
            )
            movies = movie_list
        elif self.kwargs.get('genre') is not None:
            movie_list = Movie.objects.filter(
                genre__slug=self.kwargs.get('genre'),
                published=True,
            )
            movies = movie_list
        else:
            movies = Movie.objects.filter(published=True)
        return movies


urls.py

app_name = "movies"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', MovieListView.as_view(), name='movie_list'),
    path('<id>-<name>/', MovieDetailView.as_view(), name='movie_detail'),
    path("<slug:category>/", MovieListView.as_view(), name="category_post"),
    path("<slug:genre>/", MovieListView.as_view(), name="genre_list"),
]
```

Comment: It will always take the first `path(..)`, since the paths always fully overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urls.py` does not make much sense. The patterns that match the `'<slug:category>/'` patterns are exactly the same patterns as the ones that match `'<slug:genre>/'`. So it will always takes the first path here.

You thus should make the paths distinct, for example by prefixing:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', MovieListView.as_view(), name='movie_list'),
    path('<id>-<name>/', MovieDetailView.as_view(), name='movie_detail'),
    path('category/<slug:category>/', MovieListView.as_view(), name='category_post'),
    path('genre/<slug:genre>/', MovieListView.as_view(), name='genre_list'),
]
```

Now the prefix will make it clear if you are filtering on `category` or on `genre`. You can of course make the distiction in a different way. But the most important is that the patterns should not overlap.